# laravel select box populated taking default value

Tags: php, select, laravel-5

I want to give default value in a select box that is populated with values.

```
{!! Form::label('Nomos_id', Nomos'), ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
{!! Form::select('nomos_id', $nomoi, old('nomos_id'), ['class' => 'form-control select2']) !!}
```

$nomoi is populated with values and i have a var named $mynomos that has the id of my nomos. Nomos is a territory in Greece.

I want when select box appears to show all values but to have selected as default the value of $mynomos. 
Where can i put it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this:- `{!! Form::select('nomos_id', $nomoi, $mynomos, ['class' => 'form-control select2']) !!}`

Comment: and the old('nomos_id') ?

Comment: It worked thanks. old('nomos_id') keeps in session the old value of the field and use it if it needed. Anyway as long as is working, i will see later.

Comment: you can answer like an answer to vote you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```
{!! Form::select('nomos_id', $nomoi, $mynomos, ['class' => 'form-control select2']) !!}
```

Note:-  `$mynomos` is the value that you want to be default-selected.